# How to read STDIN and write content back to STDIN in Perl?

Tags: perl, stdin

I have to light patch some of the core components within an internal software product. Due to its realy nasty handling of STDIN I have to:

1. read STDIN and backup RAW
2. parse it
3. write RAW back to STDIN
4. let the downstream system handle STDIN

Unfortunally I am not allowed to modify any of the legacy code so I have to light patch it.

My first not working try:

```
BEGIN {
  my $stdin_raw = join '', <STDIN>;
  use IO::Handle;
  my $stdin_io1 = IO::Handle->new();
  $stdin_io1->printflush( $stdin_raw );
  my $stdin_io2 = IO::Handle->new();
  $stdin_io2->printflush( $stdin_raw );
  STDIN->fdopen( $stdin_io1, 'r' );
  require CGI;
  warn CGI::param('PARAM1');
  warn CGI::param('PARAM2');
  STDIN->fdopen( $stdin_io2, 'r' );
}
```

It's able to read STDIN in the first line but nighter CGI nor the downstream system are getting any input from STDIN which I (tried) to set as listed above.

So: **How to read STDIN and write content back to STDIN in Perl?**

The application is running under CGI (webserver) condition. STDIN handles the POST data of a web request.

Comment: I'm not sure your problem description makes sense. What is STDIN here? If you can really write to it, it would go to upstream, not downstream.

Comment: I have add more explanations.

Comment: Writing to STDIN would send data back to the web server. It wouldn't let you read from STDIN again.

Comment: Per definition you cannot write content to standard *input*. It would then become output. This is most likely an [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: I don't agree with XY-Problem. I agree if I'm allowed to modify the legacy code but this is not the situation. So I have to refill STDIN to let the legacy code read it again. There is clearly only one way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read, refill, read STDIN is not possible at all.

Answer (score 2):

How about `open(STDIN, '<', \$stdin_raw)`

---

By the way,

```
my $stdin_raw = join '', <STDIN>;
```

is usually written as

```
my $stdin_raw; { local $/; $stdin_raw = <STDIN>; }
```

Probably more efficient too.

Comment: `my $stdin_raw = do{ local $/; <STDIN> };`

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, It's cleaner, but it makes an extra copy of the entire file

Comment: Actually I don't think that `$c=do{<STDIN>}` makes an extra copy. It isn't stored in any other [`SV`](http://p3rl.org/perlguts#Variables) so it doesn't need more than one copy. If it does create an extra copy, there is a bug in [`perl`](http://p3rl.org/perlrun).

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, Quick test: `perl -E"say \do{ $y = 6; say \$y; $y }"`. Real test: `perl -e"$x = do { local $/; <> }; <STDIN>" 100MB.txt` uses 196MB. `perl -e"{ local $/; $x=<> }; <STDIN>" 100MB.txt` uses 99MB.

Comment: Right now Perl creates something along the lines of `sassign(scope(readline(gv(*STDIN))),padsv($c:2,3))` (`-MO=Concise`). Perhaps it should really be optimized to `padsv($c:1,3),scope(padsv($c:1,3),readline(gv(*STDIN)))` (`my $c;do{$c=<STDIN>}`) then there would be no unnecessary copying.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, I wonder why the string buffer isn't stolen from the temporary returned by `readline`.

Comment: I have no idea. I have only looked at how Perl worked at the C level when I sent in the [patch](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/114c60ecb1f775ef1deb4fdc8fb8e3a6f343d13d) that now causes `while(readdir($d)){...}` to be converted to `while(defined($_=readdir($d)){...}`.